# Django RSS feed: any way to cache M2M relationship to display in item_title?

Tags: django, django-rss, django-syndication

Example models `Author` and `Book` are linked via M2M. I've found a way to cache the relationship in `items`, but that doesn't really help because I need to display some info about `Author` in the `Book` feed:

```
def item_title(self, item):
    return f"{item.author_set.first().name} released {item.title}"
```

Any way to somehow cache the M2M relationship here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be as easy as this?

```
def items(self, obj):
    …
    self.some_custom_dict = {x.id: x for x in releases}

def item_title(self, item):
    cached_with_relationship = self.some_custom_dict.get(item.id)
```

It seems to work after preliminary testing. Waiting for more informed opinions.